# Input query to access data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, data-access

I have a line in my code which looks like this:

```
r"/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/File/Data/Database/Station1/20160401",
"201604010000"
```

The problem is that I need in place of `Database`, `Station1`, `20160401`,
    `201604010000` use an `input` query. I don't want to create all the time new files of my code with changed date of measurement, or station. What I need is to implement `input` command to those lines so I can freely access all my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use input() then you'll have to set up variables to catch each input like `db = input('Enter a database name: ')` then from there you can have the path as a variable like `path = r'/users/me/pycharmprojects/file/data/database/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(db, station_name, date)`

Comment: Ok thanks for an answer, but I still have got a problem. Look, I have set up all variables so I have
`Database = input('Enter a database name: ')`

And so on.

`data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/File/Data/{0}/{1}/{2}", "{3}".format(Database, Station, Date, Time), conversionError)`

I am using convertion data, that's why I have some addons in this line. When I run the code, as expected I get first input, but when I type the "Wera1" (Name of my database" I get an answer, that there is no such thing. How can I define it? What should I do?

Comment: Ok I found it I need to use `raw_input`